# Weird "hair" comming out of my muffler

Tags: exhaust, smell, muffler

I recently noticed a burned smell when driving a little bit faster. Today, I found this stuff comming out of my muffler:

[image]
[image]

I cannot imagine that this material should be in the muffler. However, before removing this stuff and maybe damaging the muffler I come here to ask: Could it be possible that this material is actually meant to be there? Car is a Alfa Romeo Brera 3.2 from 2008.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The material is the fiberglass baffling material from inside the muffler. It is an early indicator that the muffler is failing. The interior metal frame work is rusting away allowing the packing to escape.

Comment: Could this cause serious damage if I dont fix it now/soon?

Comment: The problem will get worse over time. The muffler will at some point begin to get louder. The worst case scenario is the muffler will get plugged and a decrease in power or potentially the engine won't run above an idle if it got real bad.

Comment: Once it has all come out you will have a "free flow" exhaust  :) : but as pointed out it may be louder especially at cruise when you may notice it more...